# dharmraj yudhistir's dharm

Tags: mahabharata, sin, reference-request, yudhisthira, punishment

There was a huge gathering, and you were betting on
Draupadi. ​​Tell Yudhishthir, how can you be called Dharamraj?

this is a part of a poem and i know that it was a sin of yudhistir, can anyone provide me references that it was a sin and yudhistir got punishment for this?

there is a reference when yudhishtir see his brothers in hell for a short time but that is for his sin for killing guru dron not for betting his wife in the game.